# html5 js Partial page loaded to div backbutton not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Information: I am creating a website that contains links in a nav element.
When these links are clicked I want to load the content from and to the 
main div only.
This all works out great when I click the links, the url is updated properly and the correct data is loaded for some reason, according to all the examples I have followed I would have to use pushstate for that to happen.

The problem: When I then use the back /forward buttons the url is properly updated but the data is not loaded. (I realise the code for that part is missing here)

I tried it with HTML5 pushState and popstate reading up loads of questions on this problem and following several examples but I just cannot get it to work on my page.

Any ideas what I can try or what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
 "<ul>" +
 "<li><a href=' '>Start</a></li>" +
 "<li><a href='#information' class='links' page='information'>Information</a></li>" +
 "<li><a href='#activities' class='links' page='activities'>Activities</a></li>" +
 "</ul>";
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".links").click(function(e){
  $("#main").load($(this).attr("page")+".html")
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
   <script src="script/scripts.js"></script>
        </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header id="header"></header>
  <nav id="nav01"></nav>
  <div id="main">
   This is where we load new content
  </div>
  <footer id="footer"></footer>
 </body> 
</html>
```

This is how the entire thing looks at the moment. The .attr("page")) I thought was taken from the anchors "page", would it perhaps be better to use the href properly, or do this without hashtags (have seen a few examples of this but could not get that to work either).
I should add that information.html for example, only has a div id="main"   in it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //Contains the static header
     document.getElementById("header").innerHTML =
     "";

    //Contains the static navigationbar
     document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
     "<ul>" +
     "<li><a href=' '>Start</a></li>" +
     "<li><a href='#information' class='links' page='information'>Information</a></li>" +
     "<li><a href='#activities' class='links' page='activities'>Activities</a></li>" +
     "</ul>";

    //Contains the static footer
     document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML =
     "";

    //This is responsible for loading new content
        /*  $(".links").click(function(e){
      $("#main").load($(this).attr("page")+".html")
      
     }); */
     $("#nav01").on('click','.links',function(){
         $("#main").load($(this).attr("page")+".html")
     });
      
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will [Your `click event`] not work because those are dynamically attached `elements` and hence you need **[`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here. Also no need to wrap the `click event` again in `document.ready`. All you need to do is `attach` the `event` by propagating through already existing element as below:

```
$("#nav01").on('click','.links',function(){
     $("#main").load($(this).attr("page")+".html")
});
```

`#nav01` will already be present in page as part of `html DOM`. So you can propagate the `event` from there. Otherwise, use `document` instead of `#nav01` as in `$(document).on('click','.links',function(){...});`

**Just an advice -** Its good to use `data-*` attributes instead of having `attributes` which are not valid. IMHO, `page` is not a valid attribute for `a` tag. So you can just replace that with `data-page` and also you can directly store `data-page="activities.html"` or `data-page="information.html"` and use it as below:

```
$("#nav01").on('click','.links',function(){
     $("#main").load($(this).attr("data-page"))
     //Or $("#main").load($(this).data("page")) if you are using html5
});
```

Comment: Thank you for a very quick reply! Will look into this in a bit and get back with the results.

Comment: I am using html5, and went with:
        $("#nav01").on('click','.links',function(){
   $("#main").load($(this).attr("page")+".html")
  });
Also moved it inside the same document.ready as the others, tried having it outside but that would not work. even if I moved the loading of script to the bottom of source.html. So far this gives me the same result as before. using .data("page")) would not work however. And after reading up on event delegation I have a slightly better understanding of what I'm doing, but not how to solve the problem.
Saving that link for later, great info.
Cheers

Comment: Should I have updated my initial question with replacement for the new code instead of made it an answer to the thread perhaps? Not sure how those things work here yet. If so, I will remove the answer and instead edit the initial post.

Comment: Yes.. remove the answer and please update the question.. Leave the old part as is and add this at bottom with Update heading..

Comment: This is the correct way I hope..
Been looking around some more and there is several tutorials using only a div to load the content but somehow I can't manage to make them work for my page.

Comment: Let me know if I can help you out anyways!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114108/discussion-between-bjorn-nevitar-johansson-and-guruprasad-rao).